# WPF DataGrid - binding together controls of different DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to bind together controls of different DataGridTemplateColumns. Here goes an example:

```
        DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col1.Header = "Source";
        FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        Binding b1 = new Binding(".");
        factory1.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b1);
        DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
        cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factory1;
        col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);

        DataGridTemplateColumn col2 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col2.Header = "Binded to Source";
        FrameworkElementFactory factory2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        Binding b2 = new Binding("What goes here?");
        factory2.SetValue(TextBox.IsEnabledProperty, b2); //Enable TextBox if CheckBox of col1 is checked
        DataTemplate cellTemplate2 = new DataTemplate();
        cellTemplate2.VisualTree = factory2;
        col2.CellTemplate = cellTemplate2;
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col2);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new bool[] { true, false };
```

I want to bind property of one control (CheckBox in this example) to a property of another control in different DataGridTemplateColumn. Is it at all possible? This binding is strictly UI thing and is not reflected in the view model.

Comment: What is b1 binding for?

Comment: b1 binds IsChecked property of col1's CheckBox to the model (array of bools in this example). This works fine. The problem is with b2 binding - how to bind to the control of another column, instead of model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF Datagrid is object oriented, thus binding between cell controls in rows is not the natural way to do things.
As you say, your binding b1 for the `Checkbox` uses a property in the model, so i suggest that you bind the `IsEnabled` of the `Textbox` (b2) to that same property.

Anyway if you insist on doing it the other way, your b2 binding should use `FindAncestor` to get the `DataGridRow` in which is contained and then dig in the `DataGridRow.ItemsPanel` to find the checkbox. It will not be straightforward, and to me, this a hack.